# Pandas Dataframe selecting columns

Tags: python, dataframe

Python 3 Pandas.

I have a dataframe when print that shows this:

---

Date  Price
2016-12-08  237.2

2016-12-19  248.7

.
.
.
.

[172 rows x 1 columns]

---

My question is that why it says it has only 1 column when clearly there are two? So when I try to access data in the 'Date' column using myDataframe['Date'] it returns a bunch of errors while myDatafram['Price'] is absolutely fine.

Comment: Because `Date` is probably your index, what does `print(myDateframe.columns.tolist())` show? How did you create this df? did you read it in from a csv? `pandas` isn't lying here

Comment: If `Date` is your index, you can use `reset_index`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: That is the case and reset_index solved it. Thanks!

Comment: A follow up question, so if I want to use the Index Date to access the corresponding data, how can I do it? Say If I want the price as of 2016-12-08. I tried the methods in Pandas documentation and it does not seem to work.